# Quick Map Services not appearing in web dropdown menu

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, quickmapservices

I have installed the QMS plug-in but it is no longer displaying in the web drop-down menu. It was displayed earlier, but since it has disappeared. I have also attempted to re-install it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which is your QGIS version ?

Answer (score 2):

It got moved to a toolbar... check that you have these icons, and the map services will show:
[image]

Comment: I do not have the QMS service icon, only the other plugins are displayed.

Answer (score 2):

You may have solved this by now, but if not one thing worth checking is whether it has been moved to the "Manage Layers Toolbar" (down the left hand side, when turned on). I had a similar problem after inadvertently ticking the box to move it there (in Quick Map Services "settings") - which removes it from all other locations in the GUI, even if you don't have that toolbar turned on.

Before I discovered my error I found that even re-installing  both QGIS and QuickMapServices will not move it back to the default position. However, if you delete the QMS keys in the Windows Registry before re-installing it, then it should appear in the default location again (and hopefully even if you have some corruption). If you need to do that, the following should work (certainly on Windows 10):

- Open Run (Windows key + R)
- Type: regedit
- Menu: Edit>Find" (or CTRL + F), search for: "Quick Map Services"
- Select the enclosing folder (NextGIS) and delete
- Quit
- In QGIS, install the plugin again

Hope that saves someone else a bit of time and faff!

Answer (score 0):

click in "Settings" - "More services" - "Get contributed pack"

Comment: Useful to know about getting the extra services, but getting these services doesn't address the fundamental issue of the QuickMapServices showing in the  Web menu